# Friendship model with rails 2 ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to create a friendship object to use it in controller?

I have the following self referential method in my customer, for friendship, but I would like to be able to call something as follow in my controller

```
allevent = Friends.articles.all
```

How can this be done here my relationship

```
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships,
           :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
```

Thanks for any help!

Update i have an extra model called Friendship and has method has follow

```
  # Accept a friend request.
  def self.accept(customer, friend)
    transaction do
      accepted_at = Time.now
      accept_one_side(customer, friend, accepted_at)
      accept_one_side(friend, customer, accepted_at)
    end
  end

  # Update the db with one side of an accepted friendship request.
  def self.accept_one_side(customer, friend, accepted_at)
    request = find_by_customer_id_and_friend_id(customer, friend)
    request.status = 'accepted'
    request.accepted_at = accepted_at
    request.save!
  end
```

And what I would like it to is in my lets say POST controller index

I would like to see all Post my friends created by like a query has follow

```
@friendspost = Friends.post.all
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question - can you add some details on your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
friends = @user.friends
@posts = Post.where('user_id IN (?)', friends)
```

If you only need the friends' `id`s to get their posts, then you could even do this:

```
friends = @user.friends.pluck(:user_id)
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if you have a model named `user` so if you don't, just switch `user` to `customer` or whatever your model is.

Comment: What if i have an array of user_id

Comment: That's what `pluck` does. It creates an array of `user_ids` automatically from the SQL query. So all you have to do is pass that array to that `where` condition. `Post.where('user_id IN (?)', friends_array)`